# Create a loop to merge columns across rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code below for row 17. I am trying to loop it from row 17 to 26, so that for each row, columns B:K are merged and take the formatting specified (e.g., wrap text). I have tried the do loop many ways and keep failing, can someone help?

```
    Sub SubmitData()

    Dim RngB As Range


        With Sheets("Field_Phase 1")
            Set RngB = Range("B17:K17")
            RngB.Merge
            RngB.Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
            RngB.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
            RngB.WrapText = True
       End With

    End Sub
```

Comment: You're using a `With` but there is no period before `Range`.  Try `Set RngB = .Range("B17:K17")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `For` loop sounds more appropriate since you have a determined range of rows you want to merge: 17 - 26.

Try this:

```
Sub SubmitData()

    Dim RngB As Range

    With Sheets("Field_Phase 1")

        Dim row As Long
        For row = 17 To 26
            Set RngB = .Range(.Cells(row, 2), .Cells(row, 11))
            RngB.Merge
            RngB.Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
            RngB.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
            RngB.WrapText = True
        Next row
   End With

End Sub
```

Note the `.` which connects the `.Range` and `.Cells` to the `With` statement.

You could also have done something like this:

```
Set RngB = .Range("B" & row & ":K" & row)
```

But, I like the R1C1 version better.